# How does nhibernate store TimeSpan in Mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a `TimeSpan` field stored by NHibernate in a MySQL database. The fluent mapping looks like this:

```
Map(x => x.StartTime);
Map(x => x.EndTime);
```

Nothing special, no special types set.

In the DB, 13:00 and 14:00 show up respectively 468000000000 and 504000000000 in the DB. The field type is BIGINT (int64)

In a stored procedure, I need to calculate the amount of hours difference there is between the 2 timestamps.

The numbers seem to represent the number of uSeconds elapsed...

Except they don't

Take the first number for example: 468000000000 or 4.68e+11

13 hours is 4.68e+10 microseconds...

SO is it really storing elapsed time as 1/100ths of a nanosecond???

Comment: Note that this behavior depends on the `type` specified on mappings. Not specifying one for a .Net `TimeSpan` defaults to db type `Int64`. But you can change that to `Time` if your db supports it. See the [(not up-to-date) list](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes), or check [NHibernate code](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/NHibernateUtil.cs).

Answer (score 0):

So yes it actually stores 1/100ths of a nanoseconds.

Divide by 3.6e+10 to get the value in hours.

Neat!